# Call another function within a function and pass array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, function

I have a page called `main.php` which includes a file titled `functions.php`. The `main.php` calls a function `split-array()` from the included `functions.php` file.

The array gets passed into `split-array()`. Now I want to pass THAT array into another function called `do_list()` in the SAME `functions.php` file, which then should show the result in the `main.php`.

How do I achieve that?

Answer (score 1):

You can use following way to solve your issue.

main.php

```
<?php

include 'functions.php';

$arr = array(...);

$result = do_list(split-array($arr));
```

Comment: Good solution. Could be also somethink like this: $res = split-array($arr); function split-array($arr) { ... return do_list($arr); } depending on the logic ofcourse.